# Extending automorphism from an affine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves, short-exact-sequences

Given a projective variety $X$ and an open affine $U$ in $X$. Is there a way to decide whether a given automorphism of a vector bundle $E$ on $U$, is the restriction of automorphism of some coherent sheaf on $X$? In my situation we have a double short exact sequence of vector bundles on the same objects $\text{SES1}, \text{SES2}: 0\rightarrow E_1 \rightarrow E_2 \rightarrow E_3 \rightarrow 0$ on $X$. (The objects of $\text{SES1}$ and $\text{SES2}$ are same but the exact sequences are not isomorphic). When restricted to $U$ they split. We denote the injections by $i_1,i_2$ and surjections by $j_1,j_2$. Their splitting morphisms are denoted by $si_1,si_2, sj_1$ and $sj_2$. Then we can define an automorphism of $E_2|_{U}$ which is $i_2\circ si_1+sj_2\circ j_1$. Can this automorphism be the restriction of automorphism of a coherent sheaf on $X$?

In my situation everything is over finite fields, so automorphisms of coherent sheaves on the projective variety have finite order. I want to verify that whether the automorphism constructed on the $E_2|_U$ will also have a finite order or not. It is really hard to come up with explicit examples for it!

Comment: Yes, thanks I'll fix it.